# What is the difference between evangelism and evangelicalism?

Tags: vocabulary

What is the difference between the two? They seem so similar to me.

In everyday speaking, can I use just one of them?

Comment: Fixed your question.

Comment: I've never seen "evangelicalism" before, but the "Evangelical" movement is a offshoot of Protestantism, similar to the way Protestantism is an offshoot of Christianity.  "Evangelism" on the other hand, simply means proselytizing, and can be done by someone of any religious flavor (or, by analogy, can even be done by an advertiser on behalf of a commercial product).

Answer (score 3):

- **Evangelism** means ["the preaching of propagation of the gospel"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/evangelism?s=t) (usually the Christian Gospel).
- **Evangelicalism** means ["adherence to evangelical doctrines"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/evangelicalism?s=t), i.e. those of "evangelical" Christian groups. [Evangelical Christian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelicalism) lay a great emphasis on personal salvation, belief in the Bible, and evangelism.

Dictionaries sometimes give definitions that make them more interchangeable than they usually are - in older usage they are more interchangeable than modern usage.

Comment: Yes, it's important to note that, while dictionary definitions may not show much difference, there are great differences in current usage.  Evangelical Christianity is a fairly specific branch of Christian doctrine/practice, while "evangelism" is a very generic term.

Comment: "Evangelism" can be used in non-religious contexts -- it's when you go around bringing people into the fold, whatever the fold happens to be.  Evangelical is a particular flavor of religion.